# multiple errors in installing mssql-server 2019 on ubuntu 18.4/16.4 VPS

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, odbc

I followed the instructions on Microsoft [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) to install mssql-server 2019, but I got some errors installing it on VPS(ubuntu 18.4 and 16.4).
I ran this command:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA
```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

also

```
ODBC timeout
```

they have mentioned on their website that ODBC-driver v. 17.4 is compatible with ubuntu 18.4, while ubuntu 18.4 is not officially supported.
I tried to follow the same instructions on local ubuntu server 16.4 it worked just fine.
I tried to downgrade to ODBC version 13.1 on ubuntu 16.4 VPS still get similar issues:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd: No such file or directory` Sounds like you habven't installed `sqlcmd`

Comment: I think I removed it when I wanted to downgrade but I installed an older version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled mssql-server following this [tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-ms-sql-on-ubuntu/)
then I was able to connect to it using DBeaver.
I also noticed that this command:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA
```

will not work and gives this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

So I used these two commands:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```